# What does it cost to put an app on AppExchange?

Tags: appexchange

What should I do and how much it will cost to place an app on AppExchange?
Please, provide an answer for paid app and totally free.

What I found is a bit contradictory. One answer says that to publish any app you need to join partner program (which is free) and pay for app review ($2700 one time), and other says that for free you just need to join and no need to pay for a review.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To list on the app exchange you need to be a partner. If the app is a paid managed app you will have to pay the security review fee. Unmanaged apps cannot be listed IIRC

Additionally you will have a Revenue share (something like 25% now I think) with SF.

The cost would be the $2,700. The impact on revenue would be 25% of collected revenue from the app. So not a cost but would have to be factored into your pricing or accounted for in your business forecasting. (Depends on your definition of cost :) )

someone please correct / update this answer if I am mistaken.

Comment: So, regardless of is your app free or paid, you must pay review fee in order to make your app available in AppExchange, correct?

Comment: @Chiz - no, Free Managed apps are no cost review unless it has changed. Updated answer for clarity

Comment: for free app, you will have a cost of $150 per year

Comment: I think the revenue is 15% now - https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/05/how-appexchange-is-empowering-companies.html "And to make sure we’re empowering businesses of every size and in every stage of growth to embrace growing opportunities in the Salesforce economy, we’re lowering percent net revenue—or the baseline revenue-sharing model for ISVs in our ecosystem—from 25% to 15%"

Comment: Their official documentation says it's still 25%. 
"An ISV partner shares 25 percent of their net revenue"
https://partners.salesforce.com/s/ISVPartnerProgramGuidePY2018.pdf